# How to remove regular expressions in a string in R?

Tags: regex, string, r

The string is `"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLocation\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSan Francisco, CA;Oakland, CA"` and I want it to be shown as `"Location","San Francisco, CA;Oakland, CA"`.

Is there a function for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regular expression to remove the special characters:

```
x <-"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLocation\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSan Francisco, CA;Oakland, CA"

gsub('[\r\n\t]', '', x)
```

However, if you really have a string with all those `\` the answer becomes something more like:

```
gsub('\\\\[a-z]', '', x)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you want the two parts of the string separated or not. If you did, you could use:

```
test <- c("\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tLocation\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSan Francisco, CA;Oakland, CA")
result <- unlist(strsplit(test,"\\r|\\n|\\t"))
result <- result[result!=""]
result
[1] "Location"                      "San Francisco, CA;Oakland, CA"
```